# Entity Framework map a object with a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I use EF6. I have a `Person` and a `Friend` class :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Friend { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 tables :

Person

1. Id   integer
2. Name varchar
3. FriendId integer

Friend

1. Id   integer
2. Name varchar

I want EF `DBContext` to map `FriendId` column with `Friend` object in `Person` class.

When creating a `Person` instance, I want EF to create a `Friend` instance and set `FriendId` in the `Person(FriendId)` column.

Is it possible or am I doing it wrong ? Do I have to replace the `Friend` attribute with an int `FriendId` ?

Thank you

Comment: First of all change `public Friend { get; set; }` -> `public Friend Friend { get; set; }`. After you do that EF will do mapping for you because everything here is under EF naming conventions so you don't have to do it manually. But because your `Friend` object in `Person` class is not `virtual` it wont be loaded automatically (eager loading). You need to use `Include` to inspect `Friend` object.

Comment: Thank you very much ! context.Person.Include("Friend").ToList() solved the problem ! :)